# Bootstrap | Link doesn't work in a div with my-auto class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, carousel

I have a carousel with 3 columns, and 1 column is used for Prev & Next carousel controls. Those are vertically aligned in a column using my-auto class. However, once I add that class to a column, links don't work anymore. I tried overflow:auto on the column div, but it doesn't help. Any advice? I'm using Bootstrap 4.4.

Here is a quick JS-fiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/vk0uL85q/) with what I have now. Any help is appreciated!

```
<div id="carouselOfferings" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000">
    <div class="container">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselOfferings" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselOfferings" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="offset-lg-1 col-lg-5 carousel-offerings-txt">
                    <h2>Heading 1</h2>
                    <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="offset-lg-1 col-lg-1 align-self-center" >
                    <a href="#carouselOfferings" class="left carousel-control small-uppercase-txt" data-slide="prev">prev</a>
                    <a href="#carouselOfferings" class="right carousel-control small-uppercase-txt " data-slide="next">next</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-img-full-div">
                    <img src="https://c402277.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/photos/2325/images/hero_small/mountains-hero.jpg?1345838509">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="offset-lg-1 col-lg-5 carousel-offerings-txt">
                    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
                    <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="offset-lg-1 col-lg-1 align-self-center" >
                    <a href="#carouselOfferings" class="left carousel-control small-uppercase-txt" data-slide="prev">prev</a>
                    <a href="#carouselOfferings" class="right carousel-control small-uppercase-txt " data-slide="next">next</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-img-full-div">
                    <img src="https://c402277.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/photos/2325/images/hero_small/mountains-hero.jpg?1345838509">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hard to help without seeing your code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ You will need to show the code you have so that SO contributors can help you. Visit SO Help Center for guidelines, including the FAQ on showing a Minimal Reproducible Example >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you for the input, I attached the code. @AkberIqbal

Comment: Where exactly are you using `.my-auto` class and what does it have to do with the question being asked (besides being in the title, for no apparent reason)?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu unfortunately, I did not attach the code right away. In the meantime, I was trying to figure it out by myself and used a different class. Thank you, however, for your effort and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override `.carousel-indicator`'s `position:absolute` with [`relative`](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/4ej59Lam/).

Without it, in conjunction with your current CSS, it covers the entire carousel, effectively disabling pointer interactions with it:

[image: current area of indicators]

---

Another option (if you want to keep the `position` for whatever reason), is to give it [`display: inline-flex`](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/4ej59Lam/7/) (which limits it to its contents - the indicators).

---

As a side note, keep in mind that, in general, it's considered bad practice to apply CSS overrides that potentially break Bootstrap normal usage.
For example, if you want to use another Bootstrap carousel in any other page, your existing CSS will likely break it. The better way of doing it is to apply a custom class/id to the item you want to customize and use that class/id as selector.

Even if you're tempted to say: *"I don't care, I don't have another carousel in my site"*, it's a sub-optimal approach, as it limits you to: ***a)*** either not use another carousel anywhere else in the site or ***b)*** remember to come back to this carousel and confine the mods.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer & patience. Sorry for my messy question & code - I'm new to asking questions here and using the fiddle, but you got right to the point. I'll ask better next time. Just one more thing - is there a way to align the carousel-indicators with the h1 on the left side without putting it in a carousel-item div?

Comment: [Like this?](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/2qncfr7L/). No, I don't think it's possible, sorry.